# Chrome Dev Tools - Variable hover not as expected when using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-devtools

Normally with chrome dev tools inspection you can hover over any part of a statement and get a popup tooltip with the contents.

But when working on a angularjs/typescript/webpack project only the complete statement is evaluated, for example:

```
this.data.text = 'abc';
```

Normally when hovering over `this`, `data` or `text` you expect inspection to evaluate that variable, not the entire statement.

Has anyone else noticed this in recent versions of chrome, think I've noticed it since at least 70.

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint there?

Comment: Yes, maybe its related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729223/javascript-debugging-in-chrome-inspector-variables-are-shown-undefined-in-watch